# Is there a way to execute few steps alone repeatedly one by one with different data set in cucumber

Tags: cucumber, bdd, cucumber-java

Consider a scenario 
Step 1:There are few filters available in a website
Step 2:And we have to select values from each filter
Step 3:Then validate the data displayed are based on the filter applied

Expected:

- Select a value from the filters
- then validate the filtered value shown in the results
- again select a different value from the filters
- then validate the filtered value shown in the results

I have tried with data table to select values from the filters but it is selecting all the data one by one and validation happens only at the end only and not after selecting each value so is there a way to do select and validate then select and validate like this

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use scenario outline with the example table instead of data table. If you want to execute the same scenario with different values then you need to create a scenario outline and in the example table you need to pass the data related to the filters.

This is how you can achieve.

**Feature**:

```
Feature: Title of your feature
  I want to use this template for my feature file


  Scenario Outline: Title of your scenario outline
    Given I select a value from the "<filters>"
    When I check for the filter in step
    Then I verify the filter in step

    Examples: 
      | filters  |
      | Data1   |
      | Data2   |
      | Data3   |
```

**Step Definition:**

```
boolean result = false;
    String filter = null;
    List<String> expectedFilters = new ArrayList<>();
    {
        expectedFilters.add("Data1");
        expectedFilters.add("Data2");
        expectedFilters.add("Data3");
    }




    @Given("I select a value from the {string}")
    public void i_select_a_value_from_the_filters(String filter)
    {
        result = false;
        this.filter = filter;
    }

    @When("I check for the filter in step")
    public void i_check_for_the_filter_in_step()
    {
        if( this.expectedFilters.contains(this.filter))
        {
            result = true;
        }
    }

    @Then("I verify the filter in step")
    public void i_verify_the_filter_in_step()
    {
        if( result )
        {
            System.out.println("Validation is successful for data [ " + this.filter + " ]" );
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Validation failed!");
        }
    }
```